# How can I pass parameters from parallel builds downstream in a jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, robotframework, jenkins-pipeline

I have been trying to set up a pipeline in jenkins which runs all my robot test builds in parallel and then, after they all finish, runs another build which includes sending 1 email with results for all the tests (rather than spamming with 1 per build).

I know that the robot plugin returns the variables $(ROBOT_PASSPERCENTAGE) and $(ROBOT_PASSRATIO) which we currently use. I was hoping there was a way of extracting them and using as a parameter for the downstream pipline build.

Just as a test I was trying groovy of the form below, but can't figure out how you get the variables and pass into the downstream build.

Any help appreciated.

```
stage('set up') {
node {
    build job: 'setup', propagate: false
}
}

stage('run suites') {
parallel 'test set 1':{
    node {
        build job: 'test set 1', propagate: false
        def 1_PASSPERCENTAGE = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("ROBOT_PASSPERCENTAGE")
        def 1_PASSRATIO = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("ROBOT_PASSRATIO")
        println "FOO=$CRM_PASSPERCENTAGE"
        println "FOO=$CRM_PASSRATIO"
    }
}, 'test set 2':{
    node {
        build job: 'thankQ Robot Mission Personnel Tests', propagate: false
        def 2_PASSPERCENTAGE = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("ROBOT_PASSPERCENTAGE")
        def 2_PASSRATIO = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("ROBOT_PASSRATIO")
        println "FOO=$MP_PASSPERCENTAGE"
        println "FOO=$MP_PASSRATIO"
    }
}
}
stage('results') {
node {
    println "FOO=$2_PASSPERCENTAGE"
    println "FOO=$2_PASSRATIO"
    println "FOO=$1_PASSPERCENTAGE"
    println "FOO=$1_PASSRATIO"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Jenkins pipeline steps reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job), you can call a downstream job with parameters like this :

```
build job: downstreamJob, parameters: [
      [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'passPercentage', value: "${1_PASSPERCENTAGE}"],
      [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'passRatio', value: "${1_PASSRATIO}"]
]
```

As for how to get your Robot variables I have never used it but I guess you could always use the URL of the test build (e.g. your `test set 1` job) and parse the log file or the build page for the variables you are looking for. Something like this :

```
def robotLog = script: 'curl http://your-jenkins/job/test-set-1/lastBuild/robot.log', returnStdout: true // First determine which URL corresponds to the robot.log file, or use the main page of your build.
def percentageMatcher = robotLog.trim() =~ 'Pass percentage.*(\\d+)%'  // Again, find the exact regex here
def 1_PASSPERCENTAGE = percentageMatcher[0][1]

... // Same thing with pass ratio...
```

Comment: Thats really helpful for the downstream part,

the other part was that what I have does not actually read the variables from the builds correctly, I wasn't sure how to get those variables and pull them out. They are created by the robot plugin, rather than being standard. Any ideas on that?